rsync unable to write to mtp device (phone)
Motorola Stylus 5g 2023
Phone mounts on caja as "mtp://motorola_moto_g_power_ZY227ZM8RH/android/Music/carchip".
Shows also in "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=motorola_moto_g_power_ZY227ZM8RH/android/Music/carchip"
In USB sharing mode, I can see the files in caja file manager.
Can copy and delete files to/from phone with caja and command line cp and rm.
caja via mtp://etc... and command line via /run...
But Rsync fails  with this command:
rsync -vL  --delete-during --recursive --modify-window=1 --size-only ~/Music/carchip-pl/ /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=motorola_moto_g_power_ZY227ZM8RH/android/Music/carchip/'
Deleted the extra file on source (zzzz), but copy fails with this (trying to copy yyyy):
rsync: [receiver] rename "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=motorola_moto_g_power_ZY227ZM8RH/android/Music/carchip/.yyyy.8BaeLJ" -> "yyyy": Input/output error (5)
sent 26,509 bytes  received 45 bytes  17,702.67 bytes/sec
total size is 3,331,743,950  speedup is 125,470.51
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=motorola_moto_g_power_ZY227ZM8RH are all permission dr-x
but from there down to carchip are all drwx.
Is my rsync command incorrect?  or any other ideas?
Thanks,
Jimmy

MTP is a very simple protocol not designed for complex use cases like rsync. I strongly recommend to use a different protocol like adb.

Not to give up on this.
adb is way more than what I need.  Would write my own script before using it.
So... looking some more...
if I use /run/...../carchip/* instead of /run/...../carchip,it seems to work much better.  Then discovered --inplace (it's only music files anyway) and it works fine.
With or without the trailing "*".
I guess all that copying to temp file, then deleting original, then copying temp back to original, then deleting the temp file is just too much to handle.  At least that's what I think it was doing.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
